# onPause() getting called unexpectedly

Tags: android, android-activity

To my understanding `onPause()` is called when an another activity pops up on top of it. But in my case no such thing happens and yet `onPause()` is called and the `app crashes`. Any thoughts on why it happens?

I have posted the whole logcat below, you can search for **D/Camera2VideoFragment: onPause: In onPause** in it.

I have also posted code blocks of the function I think are relevant.

**onPause**

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        if(MyDebug.LOG)
            Log.d(TAG, "onPause: In onPause");
        closeCamera();
        stopBackgroundThread();
        super.onPause();
    }
```

**Callback state when camera changes its status.**

```
private CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
                if(MyDebug.LOG)
                    Log.d(TAG, "onOpened: This is called: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
                //start the preview only if there's been no restart or the video is stopped.
                if(NUM_OF_RESTARTS <= 0)
                    startPreview();
                mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
                if (null != mTextureView) {
                    configureTransform(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
                }
                //Starts the video again when max file is reached.
                if(MAX_FILE_REACHED)
                    startRecordingVideo();
            }
            @Override
            public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
                if(MyDebug.LOG)
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDisconnected: THIS IS CALLED: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
                if(MyDebug.LOG)
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDisconnected: cameraDevice.close() is called here: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                cameraDevice.close();
                mCameraDevice = null;
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int error) {
                if(MyDebug.LOG)
                    Log.d(TAG, "onError: This is called with error: " + error+ " at: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
                if(MyDebug.LOG)
                    Log.d(TAG, "onError: cameraDevice.close() is called here: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                cameraDevice.close();
                mCameraDevice = null;
                Activity activity = getActivity();
                if (null != activity) {
                    activity.finish();
                }
            }
```

**Start Video Recording**

```
private void startRecordingVideo() {
        final Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (null == activity) {
            return;
        }
        if (null == mCameraDevice || !mTextureView.isAvailable() || null == mPreviewSize) {
            if(MyDebug.LOG){
                if(mCameraDevice == null)
                    Log.d(TAG, "startRecordingVideo: mCameraDevice is NULL: " + System.currentTimeMillis() + Thread.currentThread().toString());
                if(!mTextureView.isAvailable())
                    Log.d(TAG, "startRecordingVideo: mTextureView is not available");
                if(mPreviewSize == null)
                    Log.d(TAG, "startRecordingVideo: mPreviewSize is NULL");
            }
            return;
        }
        try {
            closePreviewSession();
            // Toast.makeText(activity," before setUpMediaRecorder " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            setUpMediaRecorder();
            // Toast.makeText(activity," After setUpMediaRecorder " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            /**----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
            /**Setting up setOnInfoListener and setOnErrorListener to
             * handle the video if it reaches max file size or if some error arises.
             */
            mMediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
                    if(MyDebug.LOG)
                        Log.d(TAG, "MediaRecorder onInfo: " + what + " extra: " + extra);
                    final int final_what = what;
                    final int final_extra = extra;
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if(MyDebug.LOG)
                                Log.d(TAG, "run: calling onVideoInfo here: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                            onVideoInfo(final_what, final_extra);
                            if(MyDebug.LOG)
                                Log.d(TAG, "run: returned here after onVideoInfo: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            mMediaRecorder.setOnErrorListener(new MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onError(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
                    final int final_what = what;
                    final int final_extra  = extra;
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            onVideoError(final_what, final_extra);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            /**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
            SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;

            // Toast.makeText(activity," setDefaultBufferSize " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
            List<Surface> surfaces = new ArrayList<>();

            // Toast.makeText(activity," before Set up Surface " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Set up Surface for the camera preview
            Surface previewSurface = new Surface(texture);
            surfaces.add(previewSurface);
            mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

            // Set up Surface for the MediaRecorder
            Surface recorderSurface = mMediaRecorder.getSurface();
            surfaces.add(recorderSurface);
            mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(recorderSurface);

            // Toast.makeText(activity," After mPreviewBuilder" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Start a capture session
            // Once the session starts, we can update the UI and start recording
            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(surfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    mPreviewSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                    // Toast.makeText(activity," before updatePreview" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    updatePreview();
                    // Toast.makeText(activity," After updatePreview" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // UI
                            mButtonVideo.setText(R.string.stop);
                            mIsRecordingVideo = true;
                            // Start recording
                            if(mMediaRecorder == null) {
                                if(MyDebug.LOG)
                                    Log.d(TAG, "onConfigured, run: mMediaRecorder is somehow null." );
                            }
                            mMediaRecorder.start();
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    Activity activity = getActivity();
                    if (null != activity) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

**LOGCAT**

```
 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2ebe9688 time:2777009
D/ROOT: Root access requested 
D/Camera2VideoFragment: tryAcquire
I/CameraManagerGlobal: getCameraService: Reconnecting to camera service
E/Camera2VideoFragment: Couldn't find any suitable preview size
D/Camera2VideoFragment: openCamera: Intialising New MediaRecorder.
D/Camera2VideoFragment: openCamera: Manager.openCamera called here: 1532504895664
I/CameraManager: Using legacy camera HAL.
D/Camera2VideoFragment: onOpened: This is called: 1532504896165
I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy camera service transitioning to state CONFIGURING
I/RequestThread-0: Configure outputs: 1 surfaces configured.
D/Camera: app passed NULL surface
I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy camera service transitioning to state IDLE
I/RequestQueue: Repeating capture request set.
W/LegacyRequestMapper: convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
W/LegacyRequestMapper: convertRequestToMetadata - Ignoring android.lens.focusDistance false, only 0.0f is supported
I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy camera service transitioning to state CAPTURING
E/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-8823-1] dequeueBuffer: min undequeued buffer count (2) exceeded (dequeued=6 undequeued=0)
E/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-8823-1] dequeueBuffer: min undequeued buffer count (2) exceeded (dequeued=5 undequeued=1)
D/Camera2VideoFragment: onClick: NUM_OF_RESTARTS click: 0
I/RequestQueue: Repeating capture request cancelled.
I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy camera service transitioning to state CONFIGURING
I/RequestThread-0: Configure outputs: 2 surfaces configured.
D/Camera: app passed NULL surface
I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy camera service transitioning to state IDLE
I/RequestQueue: Repeating capture request set.
W/LegacyRequestMapper: convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
W/LegacyRequestMapper: convertRequestToMetadata - Ignoring android.lens.focusDistance false, only 0.0f is supported
V/RenderScript: 0xb7cfa0a0 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
E/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-8823-2] dequeueBuffer: min undequeued buffer count (2) exceeded (dequeued=6 undequeued=0)
I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy camera service transitioning to state CAPTURING
E/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-8823-2] dequeueBuffer: min undequeued buffer count (2) exceeded (dequeued=5 undequeued=1)
D/Camera2VideoFragment: MediaRecorder onInfo: 801 extra: 0
D/Camera2VideoFragment: run: calling onVideoInfo here: 1532504954189
                        onVideoInfo: what: 801 extra: 0
                        onVideoInfo: Thread Name: main
                        onVideoInfo: MAX FILE SIZE APPROACHING
                        onVideoInfo: Calling stopRecordingVideo: 1532504954189
D/Camera2VideoFragment: restartRecordingVideo: Stoping Video From restart: 1532504954193
                        stopRecordingVideo: Stop Video Recording
                        stopRecordingVideo: About to call mMediaRecorder.stop()
W/Adreno-EGLSUB: <DequeueBuffer:736>: dequeue native buffer fail: No such device, buffer=0x0, handle=0x0
W/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglSwapBuffers:3709>: EGL_BAD_SURFACE
E/CameraDeviceGLThread-0: Received exception on GL render thread: 
                          java.lang.IllegalStateException: swapBuffers: EGL error: 0x300d
                              at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.SurfaceTextureRenderer.checkEglError(SurfaceTextureRenderer.java:530)
                              at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.SurfaceTextureRenderer.swapBuffers(SurfaceTextureRenderer.java:523)
                              at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.SurfaceTextureRenderer.drawIntoSurfaces(SurfaceTextureRenderer.java:729)
                              at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.GLThreadManager$1.handleMessage(GLThreadManager.java:105)
                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                              at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy camera service transitioning to state ERROR
D/Camera2VideoFragment: stopRecordingVideo: Done mMediaRecorder.stop()
                        stopRecordingVideo: Reset mMediaRecorder
                        stopRecordingVideo: Release mMediaRecorder
D/Camera2VideoFragment: stopRecordingVideo: Closing Camera: 1532504954421
                        closeCamera: mCameraDevice.close() called here.
E/RequestThread-0: Timed out while waiting for request to complete.
W/CaptureCollector: Preview buffers dropped for request: 1
E/CameraDeviceState: Cannot receive result while in state: 0
                     Cannot receive result while in state: 0
E/CameraDeviceState: Cannot receive result while in state: 0
W/MessageQueue: Handler (android.graphics.SurfaceTexture$1) {63c0706} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
                java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.graphics.SurfaceTexture$1) {63c0706} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
                    at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:325)
                    at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:631)
                    at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:600)
                    at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:570)
                    at android.os.Handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(Handler.java:534)
                    at android.os.Handler.sendEmptyMessage(Handler.java:519)
                    at android.graphics.SurfaceTexture.postEventFromNative(SurfaceTexture.java:368)
E/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-8823-2] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
E/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-8823-2] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
E/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-8823-2] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
E/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-8823-2] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
E/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-8823-2] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
D/Camera2VideoFragment: stopRecordingVideo: Opening Camera: 1532504958414
D/Camera2VideoFragment: tryAcquire
E/Camera2VideoFragment: Couldn't find any suitable preview size
D/Camera2VideoFragment: openCamera: Intialising New MediaRecorder.
                        openCamera: Manager.openCamera called here: 1532504958422
I/CameraManager: Using legacy camera HAL.
D/Camera2VideoFragment: onVideoInfo: came back here after restarting video recording: 1532504958920
                        run: returned here after onVideoInfo: 1532504958920
D/Camera2VideoFragment: onError: This is called with error: 1 at: 1532504958924
                        onError: cameraDevice.close() is called here: 1532504958924
D/Camera2VideoFragment: onClosed: Camera Closed: 1532504958954
D/Camera2VideoFragment: onOpened: This is called: 1532504958991
I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy camera service transitioning to state CONFIGURING
I/RequestThread-0: Configure outputs: 2 surfaces configured.
D/Camera: app passed NULL surface
I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy camera service transitioning to state IDLE
D/Camera2VideoFragment: onPause: In onPause
I/RequestQueue: Repeating capture request set.
W/LegacyRequestMapper: convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
                       convertRequestToMetadata - Ignoring android.lens.focusDistance false, only 0.0f is supported
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
E/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-8823-3] dequeueBuffer: min undequeued buffer count (2) exceeded (dequeued=6 undequeued=0)
I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy camera service transitioning to state CAPTURING
E/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-8823-0] dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
W/Adreno-EGLSUB: <DequeueBuffer:736>: dequeue native buffer fail: No such device, buffer=0x0, handle=0x0
W/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglSwapBuffers:3709>: EGL_BAD_SURFACE
E/CameraDeviceGLThread-0: Received exception on GL render thread: 
                          java.lang.IllegalStateException: swapBuffers: EGL error: 0x300d
                              at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.SurfaceTextureRenderer.checkEglError(SurfaceTextureRenderer.java:530)
                              at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.SurfaceTextureRenderer.swapBuffers(SurfaceTextureRenderer.java:523)
                              at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.SurfaceTextureRenderer.drawIntoSurfaces(SurfaceTextureRenderer.java:729)
                              at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.GLThreadManager$1.handleMessage(GLThreadManager.java:105)
                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                              at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy camera service transitioning to state ERROR
D/Camera2VideoFragment: onError: This is called with error: 1 at: 1532504959666
D/Camera2VideoFragment: onError: cameraDevice.close() is called here: 1532504959667
E/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-8823-3] dequeueBuffer: min undequeued buffer count (2) exceeded (dequeued=5 undequeued=1)
E/RequestThread-0: Timed out while waiting for request to complete.
W/CaptureCollector: Preview buffers dropped for request: 0
E/CameraDeviceState: Cannot receive result while in state: 0
                     Cannot receive result while in state: 0
E/CameraDeviceState: Cannot receive result while in state: 0
E/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-8823-3] queueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
E/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-8823-3] dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
E/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-8823-3] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
E/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-8823-3] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
E/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-8823-3] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
E/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-8823-3] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
E/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-8823-3] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
D/Camera2VideoFragment: onClosed: Camera Closed: 1532504963772
W/CameraCaptureSession: Session 1: The camera device was already closed: 
                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: CameraDevice was already closed
                            at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.checkIfCameraClosedOrInError(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1482)
                            at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.stopRepeating(CameraDeviceImpl.java:677)
                            at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.close(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:328)
                            at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.finalize(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:561)
                            at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:191)
                            at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:174)
                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Could you post code of your activity?

Comment: share your code.

Comment: You have to be a bit elaborative in terms of scenario. as the crash is a different issue and calling onPause is different issue

Comment: I shall try, it's bit lengthy, it's for  a video recorder.

Comment: @DineshPrajapati basically what I am doing is that, while recording if the max file siize limit is reached, I am stopping the camera and restarting it internally to start recording in a new file. While doing this onPause is getting called unexpectedly..this unexpected call is crashing the app.
I shall post the logcat messages.

Comment: add your crash logs

Comment: Just a side note. OnPause is not only called when another Activity is coming to front. Dialogs etc. may cause this, too. Are you showing an AlertDialog or something like that?

Comment: @TobiasReich No I am not, I am not showing anything, and there's no activity coming to the front. This is why I am so confused.

Answer (score 1):

While learning my first steps in Android this graphic always helped me to understand the lifecycles and reason why method are called

[image]

Maybe this can help you aswell and you can figure out, which elements cause your app to call `OnPause()`

Comment: The graphic is nice, but doesn't answer the question. You should have put a link to the graphic in a comment.

Comment: I think the learning effect is bigger if you give an incentive to deal with the cause of the problem instead of presenting a ready-made solution (which I did not have at the time). At the time of my answer, the question had not yet been edited and one could not conclude on a more precise approach than to search for reason why `OnPause()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

You mMediaRecorder.stop() is either not in proper sequence or it's creating a problem with Camera service which results in the improper configuration of the camera service. So when your max file size limit reaches and the new surface gets created and it's about to preview and due to that crash dialog comes on top of the surface view and onPause gets called.